# program to run application in a different IP

Tags: ip-address, exe, c#-to-vb.net

I have an exe file that was compiled using c# and .net (thanks to PEiD). Which of course, DeDe cannot decompile. This program is IP based, so it only operates under ceartain static IPs. I need a way to run this program and make it think that I am on a computer with a specific IP address.

For example, lets say my IP is 111.111.111.111
I need to run this program and have it think that my computers IP address is 222.222.222.222

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the program thinks you are on one particular IP, can you elaborate?

Comment: well, the program obtains the IP address from the local machine, and then compares it with an entry in a database to determine certain information. I'm not exactly sure how it does this, I am experimenting with this as a personal project and I don't have the source code unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have three general options:

1. Change your local computer IP address (or at least what's reported to this program).
2. Change the database which the program is comparing against.
3. Change the logic in the program that actually does the compare.

Option 1 is possible, you just need to find out (a) how this program is getting your local IP address, (b) how to intercept it, and (c) how to return something different.

Option 2 is also possible, and may require reverse engineering the program.

Finally, option 3 is possible too, and definitely requires reverse engineering.

Good luck.

Comment: My best option is reverse engineering, I have a program called dede that does it on anything not in c#, but since that's what this program is, I'm stuck